# Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

[enter image description here][1]I am trying to make a parallel ANN network.
I plan to :

- input a 120X120 image.
- disintegrate it into 9 40x40 images.
- Run Convolutional Net.
- Merge output in same pattern.
- Run another conv-net on merged layer.

```
def conv_net(): 
    input_shape = [120,120,1]
    inp=Input(shape=input_shape)
    print(type(inp))
    print(inp.shape)
    row_layers  = []
    col_layers  = []

    # fn = lambda x: self.conv(x)
    for i in range(0, 120, 40):
        row_layers = []

        for j in range(0, 120, 40):
            # out = (self.conv(inp[:,i:i+39,j:j+39]))
            inputs = inp[:, i:i + 40, j:j + 40]

            x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
            out = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
            print(out.shape)
            row_layers.append(out)
        col_layers.append(keras.layers.concatenate(row_layers, axis=2))
        print((len(col_layers)))
    merged = keras.layers.concatenate(col_layers, axis=1)
    print(merged.shape)
    con = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(merged)
    print(con.shape)
    output = Flatten()(con)
    output = Dense(1)(output)
    print(output.shape)

    model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=output)
    # plot_model(model,to_file='model.png')
    return model
```

I am getting an error `NoneType` object has no attribute `_inbound_nodes`.

I debug a little. And the error is becuase of this line.

```
inputs = inp[:,i:i+40,j:j+40]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Todd Letcher/machine_learning_examples/unsupervised_class3/slicing_img.py", line 83, in <module>
    conv_net()
  File "C:/Users/Todd Letcher/machine_learning_examples/unsupervised_class3/slicing_img.py", line 80, in conv_net
    model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs = output)
  File "C:\Users\Todd Letcher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Todd Letcher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 91, in __init__
    self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Todd Letcher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 235, in _init_graph_network
    self.inputs, self.outputs)
  File "C:\Users\Todd Letcher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1406, in _map_graph_network
    tensor_index=tensor_index)
  File "C:\Users\Todd Letcher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1393, in build_map
    node_index, tensor_index)
  File "C:\Users\Todd Letcher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1393, in build_map
    node_index, tensor_index)
  File "C:\Users\Todd Letcher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1393, in build_map
    node_index, tensor_index)
  File "C:\Users\Todd Letcher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1365, in build_map
    node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

Help appreciated. Thank you

P.S.:I removed the slicing line `inp[:,i:i+39,j:j+39]` and it runs ok.

Image shows what I intend to do. The only difference is that I want to split the image into 9 tiles. Here the same image is fed to all the parallel Conv-nets.

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7nt0.png
```

Comment: What do you pretend to do by indexing an Input?

Comment: It doesn't look like you add any features to `inp`. The array has been initialized with shape `120 x 120 x 1`, but I'm not seeing where you are putting any data into it. I'm not familiar with the libraries you're using, but it could be interpreting empty arrays as `None`s

Comment: The traceback you give doesn't directly point to the line you think is the source of the problem. The exception happens at the end of the function, when you're trying to create the `Model`. Maybe it's caused by problems earlier, but that's not entirely obvious, and so you might want to describe why you think the slice line is the problem. The only other thing that looks a little sketchy in the code is `con = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(inputs)`, where you use the last `inputs` value from the loop. You might want `inp` there instead.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro this is just the model, data will be fed during training of the model

Comment: @Blckknght, it should be `merged` instead of `inputs`. changed!

Answer (score 1):

Finally arrived at an answer. Although I am still wondering why my previous code threw error, I just add lambda layers to split.

```
    def conv_net(self): # Add dropout if  Overfiting  
    input_shape = [120,120,1]

    inp=Input(shape=input_shape)
    col_layers  = []
    def sliced(x,i,j):
        return x[:,i:i+40,j:j+40]

    for i in range(0,120,40):
        row_layers  = []

        for j in range(0,120,40):

            #out = (self.conv(inp[:,i:i+39,j:j+39]))

            inputs = Lambda(sliced,arguments={'i':i,'j':j})(inp)


            #inputs = Input(shape=input_shape_small)

            out = (self.conv(inputs))
            print(out.shape)

            row_layers.append(out)
        col_layers.append(keras.layers.concatenate(row_layers, axis=2))
        print((len(col_layers)))

    merged = keras.layers.concatenate(col_layers,axis=1)
    print(merged.shape)


    #merged = Reshape((3,3,1))(merged)
    print(merged.shape)

    con = Conv2D(1,kernel_size=5,strides=2,padding='same',activation='relu')(merged)
    con = (BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))(con)
    print(con.shape)
    #con = Conv2D(1,kernel_size=5,strides=2,padding='same',activation='relu')(inp)
    output = Flatten()(con)
    output = Dense(1)(output)
    print(output.shape)


    model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs = output)
    #plot_model(model,to_file='model.png')
    print(model.summary())

    plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
    return model
```

This works with no errors.